# RedirectMatch not working in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm using

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^story.php?id=(.*) http://domain.com/p=$1
```

to try and

```
301 redirect domain.com/story.php?id=xxxx to domain.com/p=xxxx
```

What am I missing?

I'm using centos 7, latest httpd from yum

### adding a bit more details

```
http://domain.com/story.php?id=449
```

need to 301 redirect to

```
http://domain.com/?p=449
```

### my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^story\.php$ /?p=%1? [L,NC,R=302]
RewriteBase /
Redirect 301 /forums http://domain.com
Options -Indexes
#RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|zh-CN|zh-TW)/forums/(.*)$ /forums/$2 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2}|zh-CN|zh-TW)/(.*)$ http://$1.domain.com/$2 [R=301,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^(server-info|bb-server-status) - [L]
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

## END WordPress

Comment: You cannot match query string using `RedirectMatch`. Use `mod_rewrite` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, you cannot match query string using `RedirectMatch`. Use `mod_rewrite` rule instead like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([^&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^story\.php$ /?p=%1 [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: you used a 302 instead of a 301?

Comment: It didn't I added a more exact url example above to make sure I providing all the possible details

Comment: No one can help you with **still not working** type comments without any details. This is working and tested rule on my Apache.

Comment: You're right, I moved it to the top of my .htaccess file and tested a url with the target string and it did not redirect

Comment: posted above as directed

Comment: Commented out all other lines and it still doesn't work... I also checked the conf file for any rewrite lines and there were none

Comment: You have some configuration issue in that case. Rule is working perfectly for me.

Comment: any idea where to look?

Comment: Contact your server admin to see if this htaccess is enabled and working.

Comment: I have full access to the server, I don't see that anything could be blocking it if the conditions are sound. perhaps there's something different about your setup?

Comment: If a simplest of rule like this which working and tested isn't working on your server then investigation needs to happen on your side only.

Comment: Ok, It's been a while testing and I've ruled out everything except Varnish cache server. now looking into whether this is the reason